# Need assistance with this Java project

Tags: java, netbeans, jdbc, sql-server-2012

i am using sql server 2012 and i'm doing a java program that allows a user to sign  up and login. However, after the user logs in or signs up they should be able to add more info to the table. but i keep getting a null value. 
My table has 4 fields... username(primary key), password, email, Personal info.
i want the user to be able to add to the Personal info field after they have logged in or signed up

```
//adding a user
public void addUser(User user)
{
   try{
       makeConnection();
       Statement s = con.createStatement();
      s.execute("INSERT INTO Person VALUES('"+user.getUserName()+"','"+user.getPassword()+"','"+user.getEmail()+"','"+user.getSlang()+"')");

   }
   catch(SQLException ex){
   xc=false;

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The LoginID  & or email already exists, \n please type a different loginID and password",
               "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       //System.out.println("Error.......");
       ex.printStackTrace();
   }
 }
```

This is my table in Sql
create table Person
(
    loginID varchar(30) primary key not null,
    password varchar(15),
    email varchar(30) unique ,
    Slang varchar(128),
    /*define varchar(200)*/
)
after the user signs in or logs in, my gui goes to another frame that allows the user to put in some more info that i want to be added to the slang column, but i keep getting null. is it possible to update it from null.

```
public void addInfo(User info) {

     try{
         makeConnection();
         Statement s = con.createStatement();
         String sp = ("UPDATE Person SET Slang = '"+info.getSlang()+"' where loginID='"+info.getUserName()+"' ");

       s.executeUpdate(sp);
     }
     catch(SQLException ex){
         xc = false;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Slang already added, \n please type a different loginID and password",
               "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            //System.out.println("Error.......");
           ex.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

Comment: public void addInfo(User info) {
 try{
 makeConnection();
Statement s = con.createStatement();
             String sp = ("UPDATE Person SET Slang = '"+info.getSlang()+"' where loginID='"+info.getUserName()+"' ");
           s.executeUpdate(sp);
         }
         catch(SQLException ex){
             xc = false;
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Slang already added, \n please type a different loginID and password",
                   "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                //System.out.println("Error.......");
               ex.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

Comment: You can edit your original post to add your code in the body of the question. Don't forget to format it, to make it easy to read.

Comment: Also, while you're editing the question to include this code - please give us a little more information on the PERSON schema.

Comment: public void addUser(User user){
 try{
 makeConnection();
Statement s = con.createStatement();
          s.execute("INSERT INTO Person VALUES('"+user.getUserName()+"','"+user.getPassword()+"','"+user.getEmail()+"','"+user.getSlang()+"')");
       }
       catch(SQLException ex){
        
    
       xc=false;
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The LoginID  & or email already exists, \n please type a different loginID and password",
                   "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
           //System.out.println("Error.......");
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
     }

Comment: What does "I keep getting a null value" mean?  What behaviour are you seeing, that you don't want, or expect?  And please, answer me by editing the question, not by putting another comment - someone who wants to help you will most likely just read the question, rather than trawling their way through all the comments to get the information they need.

Comment: **Very important** I suggest you read up on SQL injection attacks.  If you get this code working, it will make you vulnerable to one.

Answer (score 0):

First the obligatory advice to use a PreparedStatement. It escapes single quotes and other special chars correctly, and prevents [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).

```
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Person (loginID, password, email)"             
            + " VALUES(?, ?, ?)";
    try (PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        s.setString(1, user.getUserName());
        s.setString(2, user.getPassword());
        s.setString(3, user.getEmail());
        int updateCount = s.executeUpdate();
    }
```

The statement should be closed, for which one might use the try-with-resources syntax, always closing. `updateCount` should be 1 if a record was inserted.

To the error; if enumerating the column names, the code does not immediately break on future table changes, but may also **leave null fields out**. *(In general one may fill in null, if the column has no constraint NOT NULL.)*

However you seem to be saying, the UPDATE gives a NULL related error. In that case it could only be `User info` containing a null. Maybe you may give a more detailed error message. Or trace the values; info and their fields. Even the connection might be the culprit as far we can tell now.